# Setting UTC date seems to be using daylight savings

Tags: javascript, date, utc, dst

When I try to add to my date's months it is skipping November. I believe this to be because of November's daylight savings.

Here is the code that shows that it is jumped one day futher than I want:

```
var my_date = new Date(1377993599000);
console.log(my_date.toUTCString());
```

This outputs "Sat, 31 Aug 2013 23:59:59 GMT"

```
my_date.setUTCMonth(my_date.getUTCMonth() + 3);
console.log(my_date.toUTCString());
```

This outputs "Sun, 01 Dec 2013 23:59:59 GMT"

And now, when I try to only add 2:

```
my_date.setUTCMonth(my_date.getUTCMonth() + 2);
console.log(my_date.toUTCString());
```

This outputs "Thu, 31 Oct 2013 23:59:59 GMT"

When I try to set the date to zero:

```
my_date.setUTCMonth(my_date.getUTCMonth() + 3, 0);
console.log(my_date.toUTCString());
```

This outputs "Thu, 31 Oct 2013 23:59:59 GMT"

Does anyone know a clean trick for fixing this?

Am I better off ditching the UTC functions and simply removing the timezone offset from all the times? If I did this would it actually fix my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no 31 November, so when you add 3 to the months it has no choice but to roll over to the next month, making it 1 December.

The problem of reliably moving forward by months is tricky. You can set the day-of-month (`.setDate()`) to 1 before doing it, but then you've got to decide how to set it back to something relevant to the original date.

Comment: Beat me to it, was going to include some stuff about getting the last day of the month (setting date of the month after to `0`)

Comment: You nailed it. And the way of doing it is:  my_date.setUTCMonth(end_date.getUTCMonth() + 4, 0);

Comment: @eli—you only want to set the date to zero where you have rolled over to the next month, so you can't do it generally.

Answer (score 2):

Pointy's answer is correct, here's a function to allow for uneven months:

```
/* Given a date object, add months (may be +ve or -ve)
** Allow for uneven length months, e.g.
**
**   30 Jan 2013 + 1 month => 30 Feb => 2 Mar
**
** so make 28 Feb. Also works for subtraction
**/
function addMonths(date, months){
  // Copy date, avoid IE bug for early dates
  var d = new Date(date.getTime());
  months = Number(months);
  d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + months);
  var check = d.getMonth() - date.getMonth() + months;

  // If rolled over to next month, go to last day of previous month
  if (check) {
    d.setDate(0); 
  }
  return d;
}
```